# Subtotal of hierarchical data for each level using a single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table with hierarchical accounting data as shown below:

```
LevelID     LevelName       ParentLevelID   Amount
1           Level 1         NULL            
2           Level 1.1       1               
3           Level 1.1.1     2               
4           Account1        3               100
5           Account2        3               110
6           Account3        2               150
7           Account4        1               200
```

How can I summarize the subtotal at each level in a single query?

Required Results:

```
LevelName       Amount
Level 1         560
Level 1.1       360
Level 1.1.1     210
Account1        100
Account2        110
Account3        150
Account4        200
```

If possible, the output should be indented for each level, like this:

```
LevelName       Amount
Level 1         560
 Level 1.1      360
  Level 1.1.1   210
   Account1     100
   Account2     110
  Account3      150
 Account4       200
```

I am looking for an SQL query which is supported by Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Well, this is not a "write my code for me, I am not even trying" service. Besides that - are you sure you can handle this? I had similar scenarios multiple times, and every time the performance was HORRIFIC - that is a lot of data to process on demand for higher levels. We pretty much always went down to use triggers to update the data on higher levels when something changed because this totally avoided the "sum up small numbers in real time" part. If the table is larger- you basically invite the next question about "my performance is utterly bad".

Comment: I understand, but I want the data to be always calculated during reporting time, as the database is a third party application and is not in my control. Any pointers on which SQL language capabilities can do this will also be helpful, if not the full code

Comment: Well, the hope the data is small or you have minutes you can wait. And this STILL is not a code writing service. You MAY have to hire a programmer to do your work if you are unwilling to try yourself (which, as per rules of this site, is a requirement).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a tricky problem because you want the partial sums going up the hierarchy.  I find the indentation part to be particularly tricky but the following does the sums that you want:

```
with cte as (
      select levelid, parentlevelid, levelname as origlevelname, levelid as origlevelid, coalesce(amount, 0) as amount, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select t.levelid, t.parentlevelid, cte.origlevelname, cte.origlevelid, coalesce(t.amount, 0) + cte.amount, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parentlevelid = cte.levelid
     ) 
select cte.origlevelname, sum(cte.amount)
from cte 
group by cte.origlevelname, cte.origlevelid
order by origlevelid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=081a659b90d692e701806594b15b76ca) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
with
recur_cte as (
      select levelid, parentlevelid, levelname as origlevelname, 
             levelid as origlevelid, coalesce(amount, 0) as amount, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select t.levelid, t.parentlevelid, cte.origlevelname, 
             cte.origlevelid, coalesce(t.amount, 0) + cte.amount, lev + 1
      from recur_cte cte
           join t on t.parentlevelid = cte.levelid),
sum_cte(origlevelid, origlevelname, indent_num, Amount) as (
    select c.origlevelid, c.origlevelname, min(isnull(c.parentlevelid, 0)) , sum(c.amount)
    from recur_cte c
    group by c.origlevelid, c.origlevelname)
select concat(replicate(' ', indent_num), origlevelname) LevelName, Amount
from sum_cte
order by origlevelid;
```

```
LevelName       Amount
Level 1         560
 Level 1.1      360
  Level 1.1.1   210
   Account1     100
   Account2     110
  Account3      150
 Account4       200
```

Answer (score 1):

Time for some hierarchyid love. First, the setup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;
WITH d AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
          (1, 'Level 1', NULL, NULL)            
        , (2, 'Level 1.1', 1, NULL)            
        , (3, 'Level 1.1.1', 2, NULL)            
        , (4, 'Account1', 3, 100)
        , (5, 'Account2', 3, 110)
        , (6, 'Account3', 2, 150)
        , (7, 'Account4', 1, 200)
    ) AS x(LevelID, LevelName, ParentLevelID, Amount)
), rcte AS (

    SELECT *, CAST(CONCAT('/', LevelID, '/') AS varchar(max)) AS h
    FROM d
    WHERE d.ParentLevelID IS NULL

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT child.*, CAST(CONCAT(parent.h, child.LevelID, '/') AS varchar(max))
    FROM d AS child
    JOIN rcte AS parent
        ON child.ParentLevelID = parent.LevelID
)
SELECT rcte.LevelID ,
       rcte.LevelName ,
       rcte.ParentLevelID ,
       rcte.Amount ,
       CAST(rcte.h AS HIERARCHYID) AS h
INTO #t
FROM rcte
ORDER BY h;

CREATE INDEX IX_h ON #t (h);
```

All I've done at this point is add a column to your data that is of the datatype hierarchyid. Once that's done, producing the actual result you're looking for is fairly trivial:

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPLICATE(' ', parent.h.GetLevel()-1), parent.LevelName), c.TotalAmount
FROM #t AS parent
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
    FROM #t AS child
    WHERE child.h.IsDescendantOf(parent.h) = 1
) AS c
ORDER BY parent.LevelID;
```

Functionally, that query says "for each row, get any row that would be considered a descendant of it (including itself) and add up the Amount column for all qualifying rows". Because we've materialized the parent/child relationship all the way down the tree and indexed it, that should be fairly efficient.

If you find yourself doing this sort of calculation a lot over this dataset, consider making it an actual column in your table and updating it through your application.